# Geo-tagging DSLR photos with Android

Tags: geolocation, photos

Is there any app for Android that would assist me on tagging the pictures I take with my non-GPS DSLR camera by using a log of the phone GPS that Android can store?

Answer (score 3):

[GPS Essentials app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.mictale.gpsessentials) will let you set waypoints of you location, so you could set a waypoint when you take a picture.
You could then use software like [GeoTag](http://geotag.sourceforge.net/) to tag your images on your computer when you get home.

Comment: So, I have to manually take the current geolocation. Won't it constantly store it with a timestamp, like My Tracks?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a similar solution. Does [this](http://www.androiddevelopers.in/2009/10/geotagging-photos-from-your-dslr.html) help?

**Update**:
In short, use *MyTrack* app on android to generate a GPX log and then use *GPicSync* to use that log to geotag your pics.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you sync the time on phone and camera. You can edit time in your .gpx files later, if needed, but it can take some time.

In case you have had different time on your camera and GPS, you can use command line utility [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/#shift) for time shifting. For your convienience, there is also a GUI frontend for that tool.

Comment: GUI frontend can be found here: http://freeweb.siol.net/hrastni3/

Answer (score 1):

This application would solve your problem
[Geo tag photos](http://www.geotagphotos.net/en/)

This system uses the phone to track the time and location and then you upload your photos from the DSLR to a website and the site will help you geo tag your photos based on your phone's information.  Basically the phone keeps track of where you are and sends the info to the site and then when you upload the photos the site matches the timestamps on the photos with locations.